# How to merge multiple datatables into one?

Tags: .net, database, datatable

I have multiple excel files which I open as datatable 
I want to merge all this datatables single DataTable in .net.

eg,
Apr09.xls,May09.xls,Jun09.xls

All have dataas follows

Apr09.xls

```
EMPCODE,PresentDays
0001   ,30
0002   ,21
```

May09.xls

```
EMPCODE,PresentDays
0001   ,25
0002   ,30
```

New datatable will be as follows

```
EMPCODE,PresentDays
0001   ,30
0002   ,21
0001   ,25
0002   ,30
```

How to create this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatable.Merge can be used as follows

```
For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles("C:\\TEMP\\", "*.xls")
    Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;""", fileName)
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere")
    Dim TempTable As DataTable
    TempTable = ds.Tables.Item("anyNameHere")
    table1.Merge(TempTable)
    MsgBox(fileName)
Next
DataGridView1.DataSource = table1
MsgBox(table1.Rows.Count)
```